# Using constructor call as function parameter

Tags: c++, string, function-calls

Is it a good idea to use constructor calls as arguments? E.g. something like

```
doSomething(ClassA(someConstructorParameter));
```

Will the object be destroyed when the function terminates? Or if you have a function that takes a char* and you don't want it to mess up a string, would

```
someFunction(string(str).c_str());
```

be a bad idea?

Comment: `basic_string::c_str` returns `const char*`.

Comment: Oh well, it's a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporary will be destroyed at the end of the full expression, after the function returns. So it's fine as long as the function doesn't store a pointer or reference to the argument somewhere; that won't be valid later.